# How do we prevent obviously low quality questions from being migrated here?

Tags: discussion, migration

[Example](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16463/is-google-lying-about-google-exceeded-capacity)

> #### Is Google lying about Google+' exceeded capacity?
>
> Google announced, that they had to close the invite process due to 'insane demand'. Is it really possible that they initially released a product not ready for a big number of users, or maybe the 'insane demand' is just a marketing trick to attract even more people?

This question is clearly off topic and very low quality to boot. Is there any way to educate the users at StackOverflow to save us all a headache and just close questions like these instead of just "dumping" them here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That one really, really sucked -- my apologies.

The first rule of migration is **don't migrate crap.**

In general the migration process is working *okay* but it is possible to see bad outcomes if, say, 3 of the 5 voters incorrectly decide to migrate a question to a site. That's a majority, and enough to make it happen.

We have some plans to revamp migration a bit to handle this, but it's a few months out.

In the meantime, I'll see what we can do to improve the messaging around "don't migrate stuff that is of obviously low quality *anywhere*."

Comment: I guess this just is a growing pain of expanding the StackExchange. But is good to know that improving the migration system is on the radar.